Circulation List For New Azure Devops Users
How do I find the circulation list for when users want access to an Organization?
I've tried looking in the organization settings but cannot find the circulation list.
This has come about because one of our project administrators want to remove someone from the circulation list.

Belongs on https://serverfault.com .

@Pshymonz, please follow the steps below to check the user identity, let me know if you have any queries.


I've tried looking in the organization settings but cannot find the circulation list.

Please firstly make sure the user is added into the organization. You can go to organization setting->Security-> Permissions-> Users tab, try to type the user email to search and confirm.
This is because if the user is added via group rule, the account won't be listed until the user attempts to sign in for the first time.

If you are not sure, ask the new user try to access DevOps to make sure the account can be found.
After the user can be found in the search result, you can click on the account -> go to Member of tab, check the membership and remove if needed.
In addition, to remove the user, you need grant different permission if you remove from higher level, please refer the link for the details.

